# How to count how many times a value/values appear in a datatable

Tags: c#, datatable

I have a DataTable with one column (`Column A`):

```
Column A
GOOD
NOT GOOD
GOOD
PERFECT
PERFECT
GOOD
```

The DataTable result can be different from the above, so I can't use static value.

How can I iterate through the column so it will count how many of the same value repeats per row in the column.

Something like this:

```
Good = 3
NOT GOOD = 1
PERFECT = 2
```

Another example:

```
Column A
DO IT
DON'T DO IT
DON'T DO IT
DON'T DO IT
DO IT
DO IT
```

And the result would be:

```
DO IT = 3
DON'T DO IT = 3
```

Comment: What's wrong with `GROUP BY`?

Comment: I tried: `datatable.DefaultView.ToTable(true, "Column A");` but that didn't work. I am guessing I first have to get the unique rows and then cycle through the datatable and add to a counter?

Comment: If you want to iterate manually then you can do, well, exactly that.  Loop over the records and add/increment values in say a `Dictionary<string, int>`.  If the string is in the dictionary, increment the value.  If it isn't, add it with a `1`.  At the end of the loop, you'll have the information you're looking for.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use `AsEnumerable`, and some LINQ over the `DataRow` to group the items by their value, and get the count:

```
var dt = new DataTable();
dt.Columns.Add("A");
dt.Rows.Add("GOOD");
dt.Rows.Add("NOT GOOD");
dt.Rows.Add("GOOD");
dt.Rows.Add("PERFECT");
dt.Rows.Add("PERFECT");
dt.Rows.Add("GOOD");

var result = dt.AsEnumerable()
               .GroupBy(r => r.Field<string>("A"))
               .Select(r => new
                            {
                               Str = r.Key,
                               Count = r.Count()
                            });

foreach (var item in result)
{
    Console.WriteLine($"{item.Str} : {item.Count}");
}
```

> GOOD : 3
>
> NOT GOOD : 1
>
> PERFECT : 2

I'm creating groups based on the value of Column "A" for each row, and then getting the string value and the count.

Comment: `AsEnumerable` **is** an extension for DataTable,  in the System.Data namespace.

Comment: Odd. I have that namespace in my solution :/

Comment: Looks like it came about in .NET 3.5

Comment: Had to add the following dll: `System.Data.DataTableExtensions`... :)

Comment: @Si8 good call, i actually didn't realize it was in a different assembly

Comment: I realized I had to use linq and when I saw the code it hit me. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

You can use linq to group columns from datatable:

```
  var groups = dt.AsEnumerable()
                .GroupBy(r => r.Field<ColumnType>("columnName"), 
                (row, g) => new { Column = row, count = g.Count() });
```

Comment: Thank you for the solution. +1 for the answer